# Pandas: Multiple columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data (2 columns, 4 rows):

```
Column 1: A, B, C, D

Column 2: E, F, G, H
```

I am attempting to combine the columns into one column to look like this (1 column, 8 rows):

```
Column 3: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
```

I am using pandas DataFrame and have tried using different functions with no success (`append`, `concat`, etc.). Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update**

pandas has a built in method for this [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) which does what you want see the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410083/pandas-multiple-columns-into-one-column/48785561?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C18.7787#48785561).

This was my first answer before I knew about `stack` many years ago:

```
In [227]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Column 2':['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']})
df
Out[227]:
  Column 1 Column 2
0        A        E
1        B        F
2        C        G
3        D        H

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [228]:

df['Column 1'].append(df['Column 2']).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[228]:
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
6    G
7    H
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 42):

The trick is to use [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df.stack().reset_index()
    
   level_0   level_1  0
0        0  Column 1  A
1        0  Column 2  E
2        1  Column 1  B
3        1  Column 2  F
4        2  Column 1  C
5        2  Column 2  G
6        3  Column 1  D
7        3  Column 2  H
```

Comment: Aren't the values in the rightmost column of this answer in a wrong order compared to a column asked for by the OP?

Answer (score 11):

You can flatten the values in column direction using `ravel`, is much faster.

```
In [1238]: df
Out[1238]:
  Column 1 Column 2
0        A        E
1        B        F
2        C        G
3        D        H

In [1239]: pd.Series(df.values.ravel('F'))
Out[1239]:
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
6    G
7    H
dtype: object
```

---

Details

Medium

```
In [1245]: df.shape
Out[1245]: (4000, 2)

In [1246]: %timeit pd.Series(df.values.ravel('F'))
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.2 µs per loop

In [1247]: %timeit df['Column 1'].append(df['Column 2']).reset_index(drop=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 816 µs per loop
```

Large

```
In [1249]: df.shape
Out[1249]: (40000, 2)

In [1250]: %timeit pd.Series(df.values.ravel('F'))
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.5 µs per loop

In [1251]: %timeit df['Column 1'].append(df['Column 2']).reset_index(drop=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop
```

Comment: `df.values` is thunking out to the underlying array, and calling `numpy.ravel()` on it. But pandas offers `stack()`.

Comment: `DataFrame.to_numpy()` is preferred to `DataFrame.values`.

Answer (score 4):

What you appear to be asking is simply for help on creating another view of your data. If there is no reason those data are in two columns in the first place then just create one column. If however you need to combine them for presentation in some other tool you can do something like:

```
import itertools as it, pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({1:['a','b','c','d'],2:['e','f','g','h']})
sorted(it.chain(*df.values))
# -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in test:
 for index, row in test.iterrows():
  print(row[column])
```

try this, and instead of printing add the value to a df