# How to print one 'column' after another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas that consists of 600 columns and 8 rows. I want to produce a list that consists of column[0] (with its 8 rows) followed by column[1], then column[2].... column[600] in one big list. I tried to 'iterate' but cannot iterate with a loop (ie: for j in variablelist: biglist.append(variablelist[j]).

Although there is a solution here ([Pandas: Multiple columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410083/pandas-multiple-columns-into-one-column)) for combining two columns, I have a few hundred to combine.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.iteritems()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html):

```
columns = [ series for colname, series in df.iteritems() ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for my purposes. What that code does is that it reads off row 0 and turns it into a column. What I wanted was to change [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]] -> [a,d,g, b, e, h, c, f, i] instead of [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i] and using df.flatten(F) was the easiest way

Comment: @user1745691 first transpose your dataframe, then apply my solution: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html