# Pandas - identify unique triplets from a df

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which represents unique items. Each item is uniquely identified by a set of `varA`, `varB`, and `varC` (so each item has 0 to n values for `varA`, `varB`, or `varC`). My df has multiple raws per unique item, with various combination of `varA`, `varB`, and `varC`.

The df is like this (`ID` is unique in the column, but it doesn't represent the unique item).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'varA':['a', 'd', 'a', 'm','Z'],
                   'varB':['b', 'e', 'k', 'e',NaN],
                   'varC':['c', 'f', 'l', NaN ,'t']})
```

So in the df here, you can see that:

- 1 and 3 are the same item with: {varA:[a], varB:[b,k], varC: [c,l]}.
- 2 and 4 is also the same: {varA:[d,m], varB:[e], varC: [f]}

I would like to identify every unique item, give them a unique id, and store their information.

The code I have written is terribly inefficient:

- *Step1*: I walk through each row of the dataframe and make a list of each variable

  - When the three variables are new, it's a new item and I give it an id.
  - When either of the variable is know, I store the new ones in their respective list and keep walking to the next row
- *Step2*: Once I walked all the dataframe, I have two subsets:

  - 1 with a unique id,
  - the other one without unique id, but whose information can be found in the ones that have unique id, either with `varA`, `varB`, or `varC`. So quite uglily I merge successively on either variable, and find the unique id.
- *Result*: I have the same df than at the start, but with a column of repeated unique identifiers.

This works well with 20,000 rows in entry with `varA` and `varB`. This is running very slow and dying before the end (between Step1 and Step2) on 100,000 rows, and I need to make it on 1,000,000 rows.

Any pandanique way of doing this?

Comment: Could you provide your expected outcome?

Comment: Will you give a unique ID to 1 and 2 given that respectively 3 and 4 are the same? (meaning do you retain the first occurence of a duplicate?)

Comment: I would like to give the same unique ID to 1 and 3, and the same to 2 and 4. Similar to your answer (really cool stuff!), but each row should have a value for unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chained boolean indexing using `duplicated` ([pd.Series.duplicated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html)):

If you want to keep the first occurence of a duplicated:

```
myfilter = ~df.varA.duplicated(keep='first') & \
           ~df.varB.duplicated(keep='first') & \
           ~df.varC.duplicated(keep='first')
```

If you don't want to

```
myfilter = ~df.varA.duplicated(keep=False) & \
           ~df.varB.duplicated(keep=False) & \
           ~df.varC.duplicated(keep=False)
```

Then you can for example give these an incremental uniqueID:

```
df.ix[myfilter, 'uniqueID'] = np.arange(myfilter.sum(), dtype='int')
df


   ID varA varB varC  uniqueID
0   1    a    b    c       0.0
1   2    d    e    f       1.0
2   3    a    k    l       NaN
3   4    m    e  NaN       NaN
4   5    Z  NaN    t       2.0
```

Comment: I'm actually having some trouble when I have duplicates where two values (say varA and varB) are twice in but the last value for varC is NaN. It seems not to be filtered.

Comment: I eventually found a way to do it. I made a mask with random values and a constant string to replace all the NaN. I removed them at the end of the identification. To fill in all the NaN in the uniqueID I used a group consecutively on each variable

Also, your code is way faster on strings that integers. I guess the duplicated in quite slow on integers.

Thanks a lot again for showing me the way