# Append two columns into one and separate them with an empty row pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append, row

I need to append two columns into one and separate them with an empty row

this is the **current code** (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410083/pandas-multiple-columns-into-one-column/48785561#48785561)) :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Column 2':['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],'Column 3':['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']})
df['col']=df['Column 1'].append(df['Column 2']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**output:**

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 col
0        A        E        I   A
1        B        F        J   B
2        C        G        K   C
3        D        H        L   D
```

**desired output:**

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 col
0        A        E        I   A
1        B        F        J   B
2        C        G        K   C
3        D        H        L   D
4      nan      nan      nan nan
5      nan      nan      nan   E
6      nan      nan      nan   F
7      nan      nan      nan   G
8      nan      nan      nan   H
```

is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a `Series` of two columns and then use right join to add the column along with extra values into the dataframe.

Use `right` [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Column 2':['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],'Column 3':['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']})
col=df['Column 1'].append(Series(np.nan)).append(df['Column 2']).reset_index(drop=True)
col.name='col'
df = df.join(col, how='right')
print(df)
```

Comment: the completely null rows is still outstanding

Answer (score 4):

My idea is to use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],'Column 2':['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],'Column 3':['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']})
col = df['Column 1'].append(pd.Series(float('nan'))).append(df['Column 2']).reset_index(drop=True)

df = pd.concat([df, col], axis=1)

print(df)
```

---

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Column 3    0
0        A        E        I    A
1        B        F        J    B
2        C        G        K    C
3        D        H        L    D
4      NaN      NaN      NaN  NaN
5      NaN      NaN      NaN    E
6      NaN      NaN      NaN    F
7      NaN      NaN      NaN    G
8      NaN      NaN      NaN    H
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done

```
df['col']=df['Column 1']
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Column 2':[np.nan]}).append(df[['Column 2']]).rename(columns={'Column 2':'col'})).reset_index(drop=True)

df
Out[127]: 
  Column 1 Column 2 Column 3  col
0        A        E        I    A
1        B        F        J    B
2        C        G        K    C
3        D        H        L    D
4      NaN      NaN      NaN  NaN
5      NaN      NaN      NaN    E
6      NaN      NaN      NaN    F
7      NaN      NaN      NaN    G
8      NaN      NaN      NaN    H
```