# Multiple columns into one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large table with multiple columns as input table in below format:

```
Col-A   Col-B       Col-C       Col-D   Col-E   Col-F
001     10          01/01/2020  123456  123123  123321
001     20          01/02/2020  123456  123111
002     10          01/03/2020  111000  111123
```

And I'd like to write a code such that it will show lines per each **Col-A** and so that instead of multiple columns **Col-D,E,F**    I will only have Col-D:

```
Col-A   Col-B       Col-C       Col-D   
001     10          01/01/2020  123456  
001     10          01/01/2020  123123  
001     10          01/01/2020  123321
001     20          01/02/2020  123456
001     20          01/02/2020  123111
002     10          01/03/2020  111000
002     10          01/03/2020  111123
```

Any ideas will be appreciated,
Thanks,
Nurbek

Comment: so if there is a Col-E it yust clones Col-A to Col-C and uses the old E as Col-D?

Comment: Are you starting with a Panda Dataframe?

Comment: @NoahResch Yes correct

Comment: This might work: `df["Col-D"] = df["Col-D"] + df["Col-E"] + df["Col-F"]`

Comment: ```df.melt(id_vars=["Col-A", "Col-B", "Col-C"]).dropna().sort_values("Col-A") ```?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
import pandas as pd
newdf = pd.melt(
    df, 
    id_vars=['Col-A', 'Col-B', 'Col-C'],
    value_vars=['Col-D', 'Col-E', 'Col-F']
).dropna()
```

This will drop 'Col-D', 'Col-E' and 'Col-F', but create two new columns `variable` and `value`. Variable column will denote the column from which your `value` came from. To achieve what you want ultimately, you can drop the `variable` column and rename the `value` column to `Col-D`.

```
newdf = newdf.drop(['variable'], axis=1)
newdf = newdf.rename(columns={"value":"Col-D"})
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410083/pandas-multiple-columns-into-one-column):

```
df2 = df[["Col-A","Col-B","Col-C","Col-D"]]
columns = ["Col-E","Col-F",...,"Col-Z"]
for col in columns:
    df2.append(df[["Col-A","Col-B","Col-C",col]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

You just append the columns you want to your original dataframe