# How to convert multiple columns in one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
   route1  route2
1    19.0    51.0
2    47.0    46.0
3    56.0    37.0
4    43.0     2.0
```

I would like to have the following output.

```
     edge    route
1    19.0   route1
2    47.0   route1
3    56.0   route1
4    43.0   route1
5    51.0   route2
6    46.0   route2
7    37.0   route2
8     2.0   route2
```

How can I do that? I checked that [Pandas: Multiple columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410083/pandas-multiple-columns-into-one-column) but it doesnt help that much with the new column `routes` that I want to create.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
>>> df.melt(var_name='route', value_name='edge')
    route   edge
0  route1   19.0
1  route1   47.0
2  route1   56.0
3  route1   43.0
4  route2   51.0
5  route2   46.0
6  route2   37.0
7  route2    2.0
```

If you have some columns to protect, use `id_vars=['col1', 'col2', ...]` to not flatten them.

Comment: Hey thank you. Actually the column names should be the opposite.